# Wait until all XHR requests in a for loop are done before moving to next action

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Being a JS noob, I've been constantly failing at this for days now. I need to wait until all the XHR requests in a for loop are done, then move on to the next action. How do I do this?

Here's one of the snippets:

```
window.onload = function () {
    (function () {
        var xhr = []

        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
            (function () {
                xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest()
                xhr[i].open('GET', 'http://www.example.com')
                xhr[i].send()
                console.log('done')
            })()
        }
        console.log('Done')

    })()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The calls inside the function are synchronous calls. And even if your function call is asynchronous, the for loop is synchronous. You will have to wrap the for loop inside a sync function to get your desired output.

```
window.onload = function () {
   setTimeout(()=>{
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
            xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr[i].open('GET', 'http://www.example.com')
            xhr[i].send()
            console.log('done')
      }
   }, 1000);
   console.log("Done");
}
```

```js
window.onload = function () { 
  (async function () {
    var xhr = [] 
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) { 
      xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest() 
      xhr[i].open('GET', 'keshavbist.com.np') 
      await xhr[i].send() 
      console.log('done') 
    } 
    console.log('Done') 
  })()
}
```

Comment: one issue is still there that the last line `console.log("Done")` gets printed at very first before all the XHRs are done.
I need to make sure all the XHRs are done and then move on to the next tasks. How can I do that?

Comment: Then you can use async-await something like code on the snippet above.